# Propane heater steady runs ,, room temperature is 5-6 degrees below setting

Tags: propane

Heater is running continually  ,room temperature is like 68-70. Monitor is on 66 but air temperature reading is 61

Comment: How are you measuring the room temperature?  It sounds like the thermostat's getting a bogus reading, so it doesn't know the room's reached setpoint and thus calls for heat all the time...

Comment: it is unclear what is your question

Comment: It's quite possible that the heating capacity of the heater is BELOW that needed to heat that particular space.  In that case under some circumstances of outside temperature and other things like wind, you may never be able to achieve temperature above a certain point.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.